# Paginated searching... does performance degrade heavily after N records?

Tags: sql-server, performance, full-text-search

I just tried the following query on YouTube:

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=test&search=tag&page=100

and received the error message:

> Sorry, YouTube does not serve more than 1000 results for any query.
>   (You asked for results starting from 2000.)

I also tried Google search for "test", and although it said there were about 3.44 billion results, I was only able to get to page 82 (or about 820 results).

This leads me to wonder, does performance start to degrade with paginated searches after N records (specifically wondering about with ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server or similar feature in other DB systems), or are YouTube/Google doing this for other reasons? Granted, it's pretty unlikely that most people would need to go past the first 1000 results for a query, but I would imagine the limitation is specifically put in place for some technical reason.

Then again Stack Overflow lets you page through 47k results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?page=955&sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: take a look at this http://www.percona.com/ppc2009/PPC2009_mysql_pagination.pdf

Comment: You may want to update your example with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?page=34500&pagesize=50 to show that Stack Overflow lets you page through more than 1 million results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. High offsets are slow and inefficient.

The only way to find the records at an offset, is to compute all records that came before and then discard them.

(I dont know ROW_NUMBER(), but would be LIMIT in standard SQL. So

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1999,20
```

)

.. in the above example, the first 2000 records have to be fetched first, and then **discarded**. Generally it can't skip ahead, or use indexes to jump right to the correct location in the data, because normally there would be a 'WHERE' clause filtering the results.

It is possible to cache the results, which is probably what SO does. So it doesn't actually have to compute the large offsets each and every time. (Most of SO's searches are a 'small' set of known tags, so its quite feasible to cache. A arbitrary search query is will have much versions to catch, making it impractical) 
(Alternatively it might be using some other implementation that does allow arbitrary offsets)

Other places taking about similar things
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-matches

Back of the envolope test:

```
mysql> select gridimage_id from gridimage_search where moderation_status = "geograph" order by imagetaken limit 100999,3;
...
3 rows in set (11.32 sec)

mysql> select gridimage_id from gridimage_search where moderation_status = "geograph" order by imagetaken limit 3;
...
3 rows in set (4.59 sec)
```

(Arbitrary query choosen so as not to use indexes very well, if indexes can be used the difference is less pronounced and harder to see. But in a production system running lots of queries, 1 or 2ms difference is huge)

Update: (to show a indexed query)

```
mysql> select gridimage_id from gridimage_search order by imagetaken limit 10;
...
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select gridimage_id from gridimage_search order by imagetaken limit 100000,10;
...
10 rows in set (1.70 sec)
```

Comment: So even when sorted by an index column there will be a large performance penalty on high offsets?

Comment: Updated to add an example of a query that does use an index.

Answer (score 0):

It's a TOP clause designed to limit the amount of physical reads that the database has to perform, which limits the amount of time that the query takes. Imagine you have 82 billion links to stories about "Japan" in your database. What if someone queries "Japan"? Are all 82 billion results really going to be clicked? No. The user needs the top 1000 most relevant results. When the search is generic, like "test", there is no way to determine relevance. In this case, YouTube/Google has to limit the volume returned so other users aren't affected by generic searches.  What's faster, returning 1,000 results or 82,000,000,000 results?

Comment: Yes but you're not returning the entire amount, you're returning a subset of it. My question is, in a set of of size N, does returning 50 records starting from the 5 billionth, incur any greater performance penalty than if you started from the 100th?